# Finding the index of a character - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I understand how to find the first occurrence of a character in a string using indexOf(). E.g.

```
Str.indexOf("a");
```

But how would I find the first occurrence of any character from an array of characters?

my code is:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];

  for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if (vowels[i] === str.charAt(0)) {
      return str + "way";
    } else {
      return str.substr(0, str.indexOf(vowels[i]));
    }
  } return str;
}
```

I would like to end the substring at the first occurance of a vowel. Is there an easy method to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) with a regex:

```js
var vowels = /[aeiou]/i;

console.log('test'.search(vowels));
console.log('cherry'.search(vowels));
console.log('apricot'.search(vowels));
```

---

You can integrate it in your code like this:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = /[aeiou]/i;
  if (str.charAt(0).match(vowels)) {
    return str + "way";
  } else {
    return str.substr(0, str.search(vowels));
  }
}

console.log(translatePigLatin('cherry'));
console.log(translatePigLatin('apricot'));
console.log(translatePigLatin('test'));
```

I assume this is not the final version of the function and there's still some logic to be implemented.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot w0lf!!

Comment: An accepted answer with a -2 downvote - never seen this before.

Comment: You know everyone can upvote if they don't agree with the downvote right?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the index of the character using `indexOf()` in an array too.

- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)

  ```
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
  var i = vowels.indexOf('i'); // 2
  ```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
  for(var i=0;i<vowels.length;i++){
    if(str.charAt(0)==vowels[i]){
        return str+"way";
    }
  }
  return str.substring(getVowelPos(str,vowels),str.length)+str.substring(0,getVowelPos(str,vowels))+"ay";
}

function getVowelPos(str,vowels){
  var retval=str.length;
  for(var j=0;j<vowels.length;j++){
    if(str.indexOf(vowels[j])!=-1&&str.indexOf(vowels[j])<retval){
      retval=str.indexOf(vowels[j]);
    }
  }
  return retval;
}

alert(translatePigLatin("plolo"));
```